# My responsive UI isn't responsive in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I created a responsive Ui in bootstrap but my layout isn't responsive at all.

I can live with the desktop version, but it looks terrible on mobile and tablet.
How can i fix this?
and what exactly is the reason my layout behaves like that on smaller devices?

you can find a live version here:
[uncovered-muscle.surge.sh](http://uncovered-muscle.surge.sh)

Or take a look here for the code if you don't like clicking links

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.10.1/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.10.1/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!--Navbar -->
    <nav class="mb-1 navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark indigo">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">HOME</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent-555"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent-555" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent-555">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">exchange
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">community</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">How To</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto nav-flex-icons">
          <li class="nav-item avatar">
            <a class="nav-link p-0" href="#">
              <img src="#" class="rounded-circle z-depth-0"
                alt="avatar image" height="35">
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!--/.Navbar -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron card card-image" style="background-color:black;opacity: 0.8;">
  <div class="text-white text-center py-5 px-4">
    <div>
      <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">

  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card">
       <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title" style="color:black;">Contract Balance</h5>
         <p class="card-text">
           <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" placeholder="AGI" id="contractBalanceAgi"><br>
      <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" placeholder="SNET" id ="contractBalanceSnet"></p>

       </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    </div>
    <div class="container" style="background-color:black;opacity:0.8;" >
      <h1 style="text-align:center;color:white;">Invest</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <!-- Card -->
  <div class="card">

    <!-- Card image -->


    <!-- Card content -->
    <div class="card-body">

      <!-- Title -->
      <h4 class="card-title"><a>STEP 1</a></h4>
      <!-- Text -->
      <p class="card-text">Exchange rate per SNET</p>
      <!-- Button -->
      <h2 class="card-text"><img src="images/logo.png" class="rounded" style="width:15%">1 AGI</h2>
      <br>
      <h3>0.00000</h3>

    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- Card -->
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <!-- Card -->
<div class="card">

  <!-- Card image -->


  <!-- Card content -->
  <div class="card-body">

    <!-- Title -->
    <h4 class="card-title"><a>STEP 2</a></h4>
    <!-- Text -->
    <p class="card-text">Amount of AGI</p>
    <!-- Button -->
    <input type="number" id="exampleForm2" class="form-control">
    <br>
    <h4>AGI available</h4>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- Card -->
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <!-- Card -->
<div class="card">

  <!-- Card image -->


  <!-- Card content -->
  <div class="card-body">

    <!-- Title -->
    <h4 class="card-title"><a>STEP 3</a></h4>
    <!-- Text -->
    <p class="card-text">You receive</p>
    <!-- Button -->
    <input type="number" id="exampleForm2" class="form-control">
    <br>
    <h4>AGI approximatly</h4>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- Card -->
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <!-- Card -->
<div class="card">

  <!-- Card image -->


  <!-- Card content -->
  <div class="card-body">

    <!-- Title -->
    <h4 class="card-title"><a>STEP 4</a></h4>
    <!-- Text -->
    <p class="card-text">Confirm your purchase</p>
    <!-- Button -->
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded btn-block" id="approve">Approve</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-rounded btn-block" id="mint">Mint</a>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- Card -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="card" style="background-color:black;opacity: 0.6;">
         <div class="card-body">
           <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
           <p class="card-text" style="color:white;">Note: 10% entry fees, 10% exit fees, 2% referral fees, 2% dev fees.The sell fee will
             only be distributed if you actually sell your tokens. The number of tokens you will receive for your AGI does not include the fees, it's an estimate.</p>

         </div>
       </div><!-- end of card -->
       <br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" >

<!-- Card -->
<div class="card card-image" style="background-color:grey;">

  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="text-white text-center d-flex align-items-center rgba-black-strong py-5 px-4">
    <div>
      <h5 class="pink-text"><i class="fas fa-chart-pie"></i> Your Holdings</h5>
      <h3 class="card-title pt-2"><strong><h2 class="card-text"><img src="images/agi.png" class="rounded" style="width:15%">1.1 AGI</h2></strong></h3>
      <h3 class="card-title pt-2"><strong>AGI VaLue</strong></h3>

<p>AGI</p>
<div class="row" >
<div class="col-sm-6" >AGI</div>
<div class="col-sm-6" >$ 0.13</div>
</div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- Card -->

    </div>
    <div class="col">.col</div>
    <div class="col">
      <!-- Card -->
<div class="card card-image" style="background-color:grey;">

  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="text-white text-center d-flex align-items-center rgba-black-strong py-5 px-4">
    <div>
      <h5 class="pink-text"><i class="fas fa-chart-pie"></i>Your Rewards</h5>
      <h3 class="card-title pt-2"><strong>Earned AGI</strong></h3>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h3>Option 1</h3>
        <p>SNET</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="reinvest">REINVEST</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h3>Option 2</h3>
        <p>AGI</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="withdraw">WITHDRAW</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- Card -->
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<br>
<div class="card" style="background-color:black;opacity: 0.8;text-align:center;">
     <div class="card-body">
       <h5 class="card-title">Masternode</h5>
       <p class="card-text" style="color:white;" id="masternode">http://snetsaving.com</p>

     </div>
   </div><!-- end of card -->
<br>
   <div class="container" style="background-color:black;opacity:0.8;">
     <h1 style="text-align:center; color:white;">Exchange</h1>
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col">
           <!-- Card -->
   <div class="card">

     <!-- Card image -->


     <!-- Card content -->
     <div class="card-body">

       <!-- Title -->
       <h4 class="card-title"><a>STEP 1</a></h4>
       <!-- Text -->
       <p class="card-text">Exchange rate per SNET</p>
       <!-- Button -->
       <h2 class="card-text"><img src="images/logo.png" class="rounded" style="width:15%">1.1 AGI</h2>
       <br>
       <h3>0.00000 USD</h3>
       <br>

     </div>

   </div>
   <!-- Card -->
         </div>
         <div class="col">
           <!-- Card -->
 <div class="card">

   <!-- Card image -->


   <!-- Card content -->
   <div class="card-body">

     <!-- Title -->
     <h4 class="card-title"><a>STEP 2</a></h4>
     <!-- Text -->
     <p class="card-text">Amount to exchange</p>
     <!-- Button -->
     <input type="number" id="exampleForm2" class="form-control">
     <br>
     <h4>SNET available</h4>
     <br>
   </div>

 </div>
 <!-- Card -->
         </div>
         <div class="col">
           <!-- Card -->
 <div class="card">

   <!-- Card image -->


   <!-- Card content -->
   <div class="card-body">

     <!-- Title -->
     <h4 class="card-title"><a>STEP 3</a></h4>
     <!-- Text -->
     <p class="card-text">You receive</p>
     <!-- Button -->
     <input type="number" id="exampleForm2" class="form-control">
     <br>
     <h4>AGI approximatly</h4>
     <br>
   </div>

 </div>
 <!-- Card -->
         </div>
         <div class="col">
           <!-- Card -->
 <div class="card">

   <!-- Card image -->


   <!-- Card content -->
   <div class="card-body">

     <!-- Title -->
     <h4 class="card-title"><a>STEP 4</a></h4>
     <!-- Text -->
     <p class="card-text">Confirm your exchange</p>
     <!-- Button -->
     <br>
     <br>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded btn-block">Exchange</a>
     <br>
     <br>
   </div>

 </div>
 <!-- Card -->
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <br>
     <!-- Footer -->
<footer class="page-footer font-small blue">

  <!-- Copyright -->
  <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">© 2020 Copyright:
    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/"> SNETSAVING.com</a>
  </div>
  <!-- Copyright -->

</footer>
<!-- Footer -->

  </body>
</html>
```

I'm using bootstrap for the layout

Comment: Note: posting a [mcve] here, within your question, is **required**, not optional. Only the link would get your question closed.

Comment: i posted the link uncovered-muscle.surge.sh

Comment: I know. That's unnecessary and, again, if you only included that for your code, it would get this deleted.

Comment: so what do i need? can you write in so that i understadn what i do wrong?

Comment: I'm not saying you did anything wrong. I'm commenting on your "here's the code if you don't like clicking links" to make sure you understand you are required to post the code here and providing links only is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're missing the meta tag `viewport` within your document. I highly recommend you check out the Bootstrap [Starter Template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template), if you haven't already. Adding the following just below `<meta charset="utf-8">` should do the trick:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

For more information on the `viewport` tag you can, for example, check out the article on [Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) from MDN web docs. Basically, it ensures that the actual device width will be used for any media queries that e.g. Bootstrap uses for laying out columns. Otherwise, a larger virtual width will be used to ensure compatibility with older sites.

Comment: unfortunatly this didnt fix much. The mobile version looks terrible especially on a samsung s10

Comment: Try consistently using the `col-sm-3` (for columns 1/4 the width on desktop) and `col-sm-4` (for columns 1/3 the width on desktop) classes instead of the plain `col` class. This should ensure that all your cards will collapse into full-width cards on mobile devices.

Comment: perfect TR4Android this worked- now the last thing that i need is do i just add a <br> tag between step 1 and step 2 to get the spacing or is there a better way for getting spacing in between the Step 1 step 2 step 3 elements

Comment: it works great on small devices and desktop but it still looks like crap on an iphone especially ipad and ipad pro

Comment: Try adding the `pb-3` class to your `col-sm-3` elements. That will add `1 rem` of padding to the bottom of each card and will thus properly space them on desktop and mobile. What exactly "looks like crap"? Please be more specific ;)

Comment: on an iphone the buttons are bigger than the div they are inside

Comment: You can either adjust the breakpoint of the columns by using e.g. `col-md-3` or `col-lg-3` (this will keep them full-width for longer) or add the class `btn-block` to your buttons to make these full-width within the card (as in the Step 4 card). Or combine these two.

Comment: the phone version looks great especially that pb3 was a great solution but on ipads the buttons in the center section (your rewards and your holdings) are larger than the card

Comment: the buttons dont behave right especially the 2 center buttons - withdraw and reinvest but only on an ipad and btn-block gets them inside the div but they look terrible- i just need them to be reponsive

Comment: Even on a desktop device, the two buttons "reinvest" and "withdraw" don't fit into the card next to each other, at least for me. Do you want these to be below each other? Alternatively, you could try decreasing the padding around the button text...

Comment: i updated it here- it looks ok on desktop and samsung s10- the ipad layout doenst work because of the buttons. I need the buttons next to each other in the your rewards card

Comment: Okay, the best I could come up with is to use `col-lg-6` for the two card columns and then add the `px-1` class to the "reinvest" and "withdraw" buttons to decrease the horizontal padding. If that isn't what you're looking for, you might want to ask a new, more specific, question.

Comment: it makes the buttons look better but now all the content inside the card is off-center

Comment: Remove the `d-flex` from the child div of your `card` div. That should fix it :)